# How to set default PyCharm interpreter?

Tags: configuration, ide, pycharm

My PyCharm installation has two interpreters available:

- Python 3.3.2 (/usr/bin/python3.3m)
- Python 2.7.5 (/usr/bin/python2.7)

Whenever I open a new project it sets the interpreter to Python 3. Since I work mostly with 2.7, this means in most cases I have to reconfigure it. How do I change it to use 2.7 by default for new projects?

**Update:** After setting the default interpreter to Python 2.7.5 in File → Default Settings → Project Interpreter and removing the `.idea/misc.xml` file, the interpreter is now **not set at all** in misc.xml. Better than setting it to Python 3.3, but still...

Comment: I can't see the File → Default Settings → Project Interpreter option in the newest version of Pycharm (2018.2). Do you know where to find this option now? Thanks.

Comment: @tsando You'll want to write a new question for that. I don't even use PyCharm anymore.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`File` | `New Projects Setup` | `Settings for New Projects` | `Project Interpreter`.

[image: new projects]

[image: interpreter]

This configuration sets the **default** interpreter for the new projects, note the **Settings for New Projects** menu, it's not the same as `File` | `Settings` which sets options for the **current** project.

If there is no open project, you can access this menu from the Welcome Screen (`Customize` | `All settings`):

[image: all settings]

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, it's also possible to access default settings from the [welcome screen](http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/5358/w2ep.png).

Comment: I want to set the **default** interpreter, not the project one.

Comment: @l0b0, did you actually try what I've suggested? It sets the **default** interpreter for the new projects. Exactly what you were asking for: `How do I change it to use 2.7 by default for new projects?`.

Comment: I want to change the **default**, as in, any new projects should use version 2.7 *without* any configuration changes. Setting the project interpreter sets it for a single project only, and has no effect on subsequent new projects.

Comment: @l0b0, yes, after setting the default interpreter the way I've described above you can **Open Directory** with your files and exactly this interpreter will be used for the automatically created project. You can verify it yourself if you don't believe the words of JetBrains Support.

Comment: I've set multiple projects to Python 2.7, and whenever I open another one which I haven't opened before it is set to Python 3.3.

Comment: Double check you set it in the **Default Settings**, the settings dialog will have [**Template Project Settings**](http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/4814/glgb.png). Is that true? http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/accessing-default-project-settings-and-structure.html

Comment: Using PyCharm 2017.1 on Mac, I set my default interpreter in the **Default Settings** and restarted, but when I make a new project it uses a different interpreter (a virtual environment I have configured). What can I do that actually works? Thanks.

Comment: I got the same problem as @LindsayWard using mac

Comment: @Qaswed File | Other Settings | Settings for New Projects.

Comment: @Ashark thanks for your note, I've updated the answer. If it doesn't work for you, contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new or report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=PY.

Answer (score 12):

This has now changed in the newer versions of PyCharm (I've got 2018.2). It's now called **Preferences for New Projects**:

[image]

Comment: Now it is called as 'Settings for New Projects...'

Comment: ...within the "Other Settings" tab (see the screenshot in BabarBaig's answer)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

New PyCharm versions in Windows have moved the New Project Settings to a new location.  See image.
Full navigation: File > Other Settings > Settings for New Projects > Project Interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a Mac and I found that on the splash screen there were messages saying that one of the xml files in

> /Library/Preferences/PyCharm2017.3/options/

could not be loaded.  As a result a new one was created.  When I looked at the files in this directory I found a number of the files were corrupted in some way and could not be viewed.  I renamed all these to .OLD, restarted PyCharm and reset the defaults to the system interpreter in my case.  This fixed my problem and PyCharm now defaults to the system interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

This has now changed again on the latest version of PyCharm. It is now 
**File > New Project Settings > Settings for New Projects**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWGwv.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you want a default configuration, right click on the text and click run, this way it will automatically create a configuration for you.

Answer (score -1):

In PyCharm Professional version 2022.1 in Linux the setting is now in
**File** -> **New Projects Setup** -> **Settings for New Projects...**.

[image]

Then in appeared window you can select needed interpreter.
[image]

However, when I create a new project, PyCharm still creates it with python 3.6 for some reason.