# PyCharm asks for python interpreter every time project is loaded

Tags: python, pycharm

Rather frustratingly, every time I load up an existing project or create a new one - it complains there is no interpreter selected and I have to provide the path to it.

There is nothing unusual about my python installation, it's sat in C:/Python27/ as you would expect. It always used to work, but the last few weeks something has changed.

I'm running Win7. PATH system variable points to C:/Python27/ as it ought to.

If I crack open commandline, the python command opens as it ought to.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your interpreter is listed in the interpreter list in the settings and set as default ?

Comment: When it asks for an interpreter, it's the only item in the drop list but it isn't selected. I've no idea how to make it default. And thats only project specific as well.

Comment: Have you recently updated PyCharm? This isn't JetBrains' support website, maybe try there?

Comment: @Oliver just *guessing a URL* found their support immediately: https://www.jetbrains.com/support/. They also have a public issue tracker, where you can report problems (or see if someone else already has): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/

Comment: @jonrsharpe I found the support page, but it didn't provide an answer. I don't think this is a bug for an issue tracker, it's more of something I've set wrong.

Comment: @VadimCaen Found it, setting the default interpreted fixed it. Found another SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679150/how-to-set-default-pycharm-interpreter) which explained how to side the IDE default. No idea why it kept forgetting the project default though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting the IDE default interpreter fixed the problem, as Vadim mentioned. Found instructions on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679150/how-to-set-default-pycharm-interpreter).

> ```
> File | Default Settings | Project Interpreter.
> ```
>
> This configuration sets the default interpreter for the new projects,
> note the Default Settings menu, it's not the same as File | Settings
> which sets options for the current project.

Not entirely sure why the default was unset, but at least now I can set it back again. The project default setting was being forgotten as well which is curious, but a problem for another day.

Answer (score 8):

There is no **`Default Settings`** any more, It's called **`Preferences for New Projects`** in the newer versions of PyCharm (my version is 2018.3.3).

For that, go to :

> `File` > `Preferences for New Projects` > `Project Interpreter`

[image]

Comment: it is already configured in my case but still have to do it each time

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it by going to **File > Setting for New Projects > Project Interpreter:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Mac: **File > Preferences for New Projects**.

[image]