# How to install python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, qstk

I need to use the QSTK python library, however the library does not support python 3, only python 2.7. I currently have anaconda installed with python 3.6.4 and the IDE I would like to use is pycharm. How do I make a project in pycharm that interprets python 2.7 so that I can install the QSTK module?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Comment: Maybe this post is relevant to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19680250/3961748

Comment: What platform are you on? I notice that this library only supports Ubuntu 12, Mac 10.7-10.9, and Windows 7-8. I believe of those but Windows come with Python 2.7 pre-installed. But if you want an up-to-date, or Anaconda-based, 2.7, then you need to follow the installation instructions for your platform.

Answer (score 1):

First install Pyhton 2 from https://www.python.org/downloads/
Then you can add and use python 2 interpreter from Pycharm | Preferences | Project Interpreter.

This video can help you for adding python interpreter:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0y5XlNeFxNk