# Can't run python file in PyCharm

Tags: python, file, pycharm, interpreter

I can't run my file called `Main.py`. I loaded it from my GitHub repository to my second PC. I am trying to start the `Main.py` file, but it's returning the error `Can't find specified file`.

I commented all lines and tried to print `hello`, but the problem continues. I also tried to create and apply a new virtual environment.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's looking in the wrong place for the interpreter? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679150/how-to-set-default-pycharm-interpreter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default PyCharm interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679150/how-to-set-default-pycharm-interpreter)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed problem, selected interpreter for `Main.py` file