# Pycharm can't find python.exe

Tags: python, pycharm

No Python at `'C:\Users\Mr_Le\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe'`

Any time I try to run my code it keeps prompting me this `^^^` but I had recently deleted `Python 3.8` to downgrade to `Python 3.6` and just installed Python 3.6 to run `pytorch`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: have  you  tried this? FIle --> Settings --> Interpreter --> Click on the "gear" (on the right) --> Show All --> Click on the "+" (add) --> System interpreter (on the left) and then choosing (or looking for) the right Python executable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set default PyCharm interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679150/how-to-set-default-pycharm-interpreter)

Comment: Why did you never provide feed-back to these comments, nor to the answers below?

Answer (score 0):

For other users: just check the "C:\Users<>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python"  folder on your PC and remove any folders belonging to previous installations of Python. Also check if environmental variables are correct.

Answer (score 0):

1.**In your windows search bar find python 3.9.8.**
[Searching for Windows][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNMxT.png

2. **Right click on your the app**
3. **Click on *App Settings***
   [Your settings will populate][2]
   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4yM3.png
4. **Scroll down on this page**
   [][3]
   [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFc1J.png
5. **Hit the Repair box**
6. **Try to run your python script again after restarting all your programs**