# Pycharm, can't choose Interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

In pycharm, choosing Interpreter option is disappeared, also I'm not able to choose interpreter in Setting.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/19679150

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question is currently unclear. Please edit it to include a screenshot if the previously linked post doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Did it disappear from the status bar on the right corner of your screen? If that's the case, then all you have to do is to **right-click** on the status bar, and check it back again from there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

follow the step I specify here :

1. `ctrl + alt + S` and select Project Name
2. see available interpreters, click on Edit
3. Fill up the information and click on ok

you can use this link to know more that help you to set up python interpreter,

[configure a python interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add_new_project_interpreter)